# Adding items to QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

I've got some problem with understanding QGraphicsScene. I've got simple GUI created with Designer, where I have QGraphicsView named `drawer_gv`.

As you can see I create scene and item, then I try to add my item to the scene. Unfortunately nothing happens. Main Window of my program is visible, i can see my QGraphicsView object, but i can't see any ellipse.

So, my question is: How to deal with QGraphicsScene? How to add object to it?

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from simple_GUI import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.createpainter()

    def createpainter(self):
        self.drawer_gv.scene=QGraphicsScene
        scene=self.drawer_gv.scene()
        item = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 60, 40)
        scene.addItem(item)
        self.drawer_gv.scene=scene


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And here is fragment of simple_GUI.py with defining drawer_gv

```
self.frame_drawer = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
self.frame_drawer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 150, 930, 700))
self.frame_drawer.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
self.frame_drawer.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
self.frame_drawer.setObjectName("frame_drawer")
self.drawer_gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.frame_drawer)
self.drawer_gv.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 22, 910, 650))
sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.drawer_gv.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
self.drawer_gv.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.drawer_gv.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);")
self.drawer_gv.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
self.drawer_gv.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.drawer_gv.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(10, 100, 255))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
self.drawer_gv.setBackgroundBrush(brush)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
self.drawer_gv.setForegroundBrush(brush)
self.drawer_gv.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 0.0, 900.0, 600.0))
self.drawer_gv.setObjectName("drawer_gv")
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and PyQt 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` has the `setScene()` method to set a created scene:

```
def createpainter(self):
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    self.drawer_gv.setScene(scene)
    item = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 60, 40)
    item.setPen(QPen(QColor("white")))
    scene.addItem(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I can see my scene, but it appears all black

Comment: @jgruszka93 
You could share the simple_GUI.py file to see what is causing this problem, it works for me correctly.

Comment: I've realised, that it appears black, because my BackgroundBrush color is black. Anyway, there is no ellipse.

Comment: @jgruszka93 
the problem of why it does *not appear* is probably because the color with which it is drawn is black, for example change it to a white color as you modify my code.

Comment: Now i have BackgroundBrush color set in simple_GUI set to gray. ForegroundBrush color in simple_GUI set to black.
And QPen in main code set to white as you write.
Still, no ellipse in scene.

Comment: you could share the full .py, I'm lazy to complete the code.

Comment: @jgruszka93 
Comment the line `self.drawer_gv.setForegroundBrush(brush)`, this is overlaying the ellipse.

Comment: sorry for dumb question, but how i can share with you entire code? Should I uploud it somewhere?

Comment: @jgruszka93 The complete example should be under 100 lines (more like 50!) and belongs **in the question itself**. Your question is deficient until you provide a complete and **minimal** example that reproduces the issues. You don't need a ui file, for example.